# Flink: Trigger.onElement working

Tags: java, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am doing functions on a datastream,

`DataStream<Tuple4<String,String,Double,Double>> price_warning=datastream_in
    .flatMap(new Splitter())// transformation flatmap
    .keyBy(2)
    .window(SlidingProcessingTimeWindows.of(Time.seconds(180),Time.seconds(10)))
    .trigger(new ElementTimeTrigger())
    .apply(new WindowFunction());`

This is a part of my code, just for the idea that what I am doing. Here, on datastream, I am doing flatmap to parse the `datastream_in` into `Tuple`, then the stream is `keyby` on second filed of tuple. After that I apply sliding window followed by `trigger`. Here I am using `onElement()` method for triggering. Finally, I use `apply` as a custom function.

When I run the code, the apply function is called 18 times (180/10, ref. sliding window) for each message that I have parsed. What can be the reason behind it?
How the trigger exactly work with sliding window?

** I can also provide the entire code if necessary.

Comment: for setting key on the second field of tuple you should use `keyby(1)`!

Answer (score 1):

`Trigger` tells where a window should be emitted. In your case if I understand you correctly You trigger window emitting for every element that enters your stream thus the number 18. The `SlidingProcessingTimeWindow` have already a default trigger that will emit windows when the processing time pass the end of window.

For more info on `Trigger` concept you can read [this](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.1/apis/streaming/windows.html#triggers)

Comment: You mean when we extend a Trigger namely  `newTrigger` for a predefined window like time window, the `newTrigger` will be applied in addition to default window trigger? or not just `newTrigger` will be the window trigger?